# Progress Bar Disappearing before reaching the end in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am trying to download video file using async task. The video is downloading perfectly but the progress bar disappears before reaching the end and it starts downloading again. It doesn't happen when I am downloading image files.

Here is my code.

**FileDownloadTask.Java**

```
public class FileDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private static final String    TAG = FileDownloadTask.class.getSimpleName();
    final DownloadInfo  mInfo;
    //public static String file_url = "http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg";
   //public static String file_url="http://imaze.net/apps/groups/123.mp4";
   // Context context=getApplicationContext();
    public FileDownloadTask(DownloadInfo info) {
        mInfo = info;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        mInfo.setProgress(values[0]);
        ProgressBar bar = mInfo.getProgressBar();
        if(bar != null) {
            bar.setProgress(mInfo.getProgress());
            bar.invalidate();
        }
    }

     @Override

     protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
         int count;
         try {
             String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

             System.out.println("Downloading");
             URL url = new URL(mInfo.getFileUrl());

             URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
             conection.connect();
             // getting file length
             int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

             // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer

             // Output stream to write file
             File rootdirectory= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),"Youtube Videos");
              if(!rootdirectory.exists())
              {
                  rootdirectory.mkdirs();
              }
             String nameoffile= URLUtil.guessFileName(mInfo.getFileUrl(),null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mInfo.getFileUrl()));
             File file= new File(rootdirectory,nameoffile);
             file.createNewFile();



             mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
             InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

             OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
             byte data[] = new byte[1024];

             long total = 0;
             while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                 total += count;
               publishProgress((int)(total*1001)/lenghtOfFile);
                 // writing data to file
                 output.write(data, 0, count);

             }

             // flushing output
             output.flush();

             // closing streams
             output.close();
             input.close();
//             Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
//             intent.setData(Uri.parse(file_url));
//             getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);

         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
         }
         mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.COMPLETE);
         return null;
     }








             protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.COMPLETE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
    }


}
```

**DownloadInfo.Java**

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class DownloadInfo {
    private final static String TAG = DownloadInfo.class.getSimpleName();
    public enum DownloadState {
        NOT_STARTED,
        QUEUED,
        DOWNLOADING,
        COMPLETE
    }
    private volatile DownloadState mDownloadState = DownloadState.NOT_STARTED;
    private  String mFilename;
//    private final String mFileUrl;
private  Integer mFileSize;
    private  String mFileUrl="";
    private volatile Integer mProgress;
  //  private final Integer mFileSize;
    private volatile ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    public DownloadInfo(String filename, String FileUrl) {
        mFilename = filename;
        mProgress = 0;
        mFileUrl = FileUrl;
     //   mFileSize = mFileSize;

      //  mFileSize = size;
        mProgressBar = null;
    }

    public ProgressBar getProgressBar() {
        return mProgressBar;
    }
    public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setProgressBar " + mFilename + " to " + progressBar);
        mProgressBar = progressBar;
    }

    public void setDownloadState(DownloadState state) {
        mDownloadState = state;
    }
    public DownloadState getDownloadState() {
        return mDownloadState;
    }

    public Integer getProgress() {
        return mProgress;
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer progress) {
        this.mProgress = progress;
    }
//
//    public Integer getFileSize() {
//        return mFileSize;
//   }



    public Integer getFileSize() {
        return mFileSize;
    }

    public void setFileSize(Integer FileSize) {
        mFileSize = FileSize;
    }
//    public void setFileUrl(String FileUrl)
//    {
//        this.FileUrl = FileUrl;
//    }


public String getFilename() {
    return mFilename;
}
    public String getFileUrl()
    {
        return mFileUrl;
    }
}
```

**DownloadInfoArrayAdapter.Java**

```
public class DownloadInfoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DownloadInfo> {
    // Simple class to make it so that we don't have to call findViewById frequently
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        Button button;
        DownloadInfo info;
    }


    private static final String TAG = DownloadInfoArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                    List<DownloadInfo> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final DownloadInfo info = getItem(position);
        // We need to set the convertView's progressBar to null.

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(null == row) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_download_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileName);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
            holder.button = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
            holder.info = info;

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

            holder.info.setProgressBar(null);
            holder.info = info;
            holder.info.setProgressBar(holder.progressBar);
        }

        holder.textView.setText(info.getFilename());
        holder.progressBar.setProgress(info.getProgress());
        holder.progressBar.setMax(100);
        info.setProgressBar(holder.progressBar);

        holder.button.setEnabled(info.getDownloadState() == DownloadState.NOT_STARTED);
        final Button button = holder.button;
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                info.setDownloadState(DownloadState.QUEUED);
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button.invalidate();
                FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask(info);
                task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
        });


        //TODO: When reusing a view, invalidate the current progressBar.

        return row;
    }

}
```

Comment: `bar.invalidate();` remove this line from `FileDownloadTask.Java` file in method `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: It's still disappearing

Comment: instead of `bar.invalidate()` use `bar.postInvalidate( );`

Comment: nope.. the same thing is happening

Comment: I have put  "holder.progressBar.setMax(100);" in adapter class. Is it the problem? and if yes, then what should I write?

Comment: no idea about that..